# Private Chrome plug-ins spend 2 days in review

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We have a Chrome plug-in/extension that we develop. We have three versions of this plug-in – dev, QA, and production. The dev and QA versions are published to testers only. These are our development versions, and we sometimes publish multiple versions in the same day as bug fixes or features are released. There should be minimal review required, as these are private plug-ins.

It used to be that new versions of dev and qa were published within a few minutes of being uploaded. Recently, however, it has begun to take upwards of 2 days to publish these new versions (they are stuck in pending review). Because they are development versions and we are releasing fixes all the time, this is unworkable.

Has anybody else encountered this? How can we restore the < 5 minute publish times that we used to have?

Comment: StackOverflow is the wrong place to ask about other sites/services problems. You can ask on the [chromium extensions group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions) where an official representative (Simeon Vincent usually) could answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a Google group like that, but I couldn't find one.